# Return value from QML Window to parent

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

I use QML to build GUI in my app + simple logics.
At some step I open dialog and after closing it I want to get back a result value.
This is sample code:

```js
Button {
  id: myButton
  onClicked: {
    var component = Qt.createComponent("Dialog.qml");
    if (component.status === Component.Ready) {
        var dialog = component.createObject(parent);
        dialog.show();
        dialog.onClosing: {} // that not works
    }
  }
}
```

Dialog.qml:

```js
import QtQuick 2.2
import QtQuick.Window 2.1
import QtQuick.Controls 1.1

Window {
  id: dialogWindow
  width: 800
  height: 600
  flags: Qt.Dialog

  Button {
    id: closeButton
    onClicked: {
      dialogWindow.close();
    }
  }
}
```

But I have no idea how can I get some return value after the dialog was closed.

Comment: What kind of return value do you want to get? There is no input or selection in your dialog.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My advice would be to not bother with `Window` and use [Qt Quick Dialogs](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qml-qtquick-dialogs-messagedialog.html).

If you want to use `Window`, you have to define your own return value in the form of some Yes/No buttons in the window, for example. When one of these is clicked, set a `yes` property to `true`/`false`. Then, within your `Button`:

```
Connections {
    target: dialogWindow
    onVisibleChanged: // some action depending on value of "yes" property
}
```

Note that I used `onVisibleChanged` instead of `onClosing`, as the latter is only emitted upon the [user closing the window](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qml-qtquick-window-window.html#closing-signal):

> This signal is emitted when the user tries to close the window.

If we follow the documentation for the [CloseEvent](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qml-qtquick-window-closeevent.html) argument, we see that it's explained in slightly more detail:

> Notification that a window is about to be closed by the windowing system (e.g. the user clicked the titlebar close button).

Comment: Thanks @Mitch, the idea with Connections is exactly what I need.

Comment: So, I use `onClosing` signal. Unfortunately, it fires when I close the window with x button and not works when I close the window from the code: `dlg.close()`. Maybe some bug in QML?

Comment: Yeah, that's why I suggested `onVisibleChanged`. It's not a bug, it just could be documented a bit better. I've updated my answer.